# create backup from directory

Tags: bash, cron

I would like to create backup from directory using cron. I wrote following command:

```
cd path && sudo zip -r "backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").zip" git/ && sudo mv "backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").zip" /backup/
```

when I call it from commandline then everything is ok. But when I put it to cron then it does not work. Log contains only part of this command and nothing more. What shall I do?

Crontab content:

`* * * * * cd path && zip -r "backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").zip" git/ && mv "backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").zip" /backup`/

Comment: You should put that on a .sh file, chmod +x file, and then call that file from cron

Comment: Please post the contents of your `crontab` file.

Comment: I know, i put it because it does not work ;) sorry for confusing you

Comment: Please follow @LnxSlck's comment ;) (you can use a pipe to a text file to output errors :) )

Comment: Try to use a full path for every command like `/usr/bin/sudo` instead of `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested i move this to an answer:

Put the commands you wan to run in a **.sh** file, for example:

```
1. vi test.sh

cd path && sudo zip -r "backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").zip" git/ && sudo mv "backup-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").zip" /backup/
```

Save and exit.

Run on a console

```
2. chmod +x test.sh
```

Call file fron cron with the periocity you want:

```
3. crontab -e

#Run every hour
0 * * * * /path/to/file/test.sh
```

Make sure the the user that uses cron to execute the file, has permissions to run the file.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because (crontab [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/crontab.5.html)):

> The entire  command  portion of the line, up to a newline or %
>   character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in
>   the SHELL variable of the crontab file. Percent-signs (%) in the
>   command, unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into
>   newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the
>   command as standard input.

As you're using `%` in your backup command, "you should put that on a .sh file, `chmod +x file`, and then call that file from cron", as suggested by [LnxSlck](https://askubuntu.com/users/49189/lnxslck).